# Woocommerce Shipping module available only for type of products

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks

I have two types of products box and drum. UPS shipping module should be displayed for the box products and for the drum products i need to get the contact details of the customers.So admin gets their details and contacts them personally about the shipping charges.

How do i achieve this.If both products are added, how do we handle this by showing a message or something where customers get clear details which products are charged for UPS and which one they will be personally contacted?

Please suggest.

Comment: if a cart contains a single drum products you get contact details from customer.

Comment: just show the message in cart or product page about this process

Comment: ok thanks. but can i get a contact form on order or cart page. as i have guest checkout too.

Comment: yes you can display the contact form in cart, but if you place order with that product means the contact email id will be send along with that order right?

Comment: yes i wanted that way. meaning that form details should be associated with that order.

Comment: At woocommerce default flow the contact details will be send according to that order. In contact form , the detail send to admin mail.